# How to start GDB for C++ called from Python?

Tags: python, c++, gdb, ddd-debugger, gdb-python

I need to debug a C++ function that is called from Python code.

How to start GDB (or better DDD) in such a way that it debugs the C++ code called from a given Python command line?

The given Python command line is:

```
python3 -m e2e.Tests.Libs.HundredEightyOneTest
```

It calls a C++ code that I need to debug.

Comment: On which operating system? And what version of Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation: recompile your [python](https://python.org/) interpreter from its source code (so it gets compiled with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information, practically speaking with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -O -g`).

Once you get such a `python3` interpreter (with DWARF debug info), perhaps in `/usr/local/bin/python3`, read the [documentation of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), the documentation of [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and run

```
gdb --args /usr/local/bin/python3 -m e2e.Tests.Libs.HundredEightyOneTest
```

Of course you have compiled your C++ code [embedded by Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/) with e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and probably `-fPIC` and your C++ functions might sometimes need `extern "C"`. See [C++ dlopen mini howto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/) since Python usually uses [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Further guidance might be available on [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

Regarding usage of [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) read its documentation. It is running `gdb`.

You may want to run `gdb` from [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), or with its `--tui` option.

You could want to recompile a recent [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) from its source code, since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), to take advantage of recent features. And likewise even for [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (for the same reasons).

You could glance inside the source code of your Python interpreter, since it is [open source](https://opensource.org/).