# Retrieve executable from core dump

Tags: linux, executable, rhel, coredump

I want to retrieve the executable from a core dump and the output of any linux package used to get this information should contain `execfn` in it's output.

Here are the following things which I have tried so far :

```
$ file kms
kms: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/test', real uid: 1000440000, effective uid: 1000440000, real gid: 0, effective gid: 0, execfn: '/test', platform: 'x86_64'
```

The `file` command only works for specific cores and it's not a generic solution because some core dump gives following output.

```
$ file ss
ss: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), too many program header sections (6841)
```

`gdb` command doesn't work for all core dumps in the same manner. The output using gdb command is inconsistent. The output received by gdb command for some core dump is not the same as `strings` command.

```
$gdb kms
Core was generated by `/test'.
```

I even tried `strings` package and I think it gives proper output but the format doesn't contain `execfn` for it to be used in my solution

```
$ strings kms | grep ^/ | tail -1
/test
```

Can anyone please suggest any linux package which will help me in retrieving executable from core dump which contains `execfn` in it's output.

Comment: Did you ask the system administrator of your Linux computer?

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question please and give much more details.

Comment: Create a standard core dump using `kill -11 PID`. The PID can be of a docker container which we are suppose to crash. But the weird thing is that the above solution using `file` package works for some cores and not for others.
Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch for your inputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find which program caused a core dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308922/find-which-program-caused-a-core-dump-file)

Comment: Are you sure that the limit (as set by [setrlimit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CORE`...) is large enough? Consider adding a (tested) call to `setrlimit` appropriately in your executable source code.

Comment: The question needs detail. What is your executable doing? Is is a command line program running for a short time (a few seconds) or a daemon or service running for days of elapsed real time, or hours of CPU time? Is the core dump easy to reproduce?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the [file(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command on your [core(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) file. But that requires your `core` file to be complete. See below and [gcore(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) with [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html).

If your [ELF](http://Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable (see [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)) was built with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging information then you should have enough information in your `core` file. See also [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325884/841108) answer.

DWARF debugging information is obtained by compiling and *linking* your program -if it was compiled with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (or with [Clang](https://clang.llbm.org/)) so using a recent `gcc`,  `g++`, `gfortran`, `clang`, `clang++` command - [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) the `-g` (or `-g2` ....) flag.

Be aware of [setrlimit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). You may need to use the `ulimit` builtin of GNU `bash` (see [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and the [documentation of GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)...), or the `limit`  builtin of [`zsh`](https://zsh.org/) to **increase the `core` size file limit**.

If your `core` dump limit size (i.e. `RLIMIT_CORE` for `setrlimit`) is too small, it is preferable to raise it and run again your program. A good developer could disable `core` dumps in an executable. My guess (perhaps wrong) is that a too small core limit size might be consistent with your observations.

If your interactive Unix shell is something else that `/bin/bash` (e.g. [fish](https://fishshell.com/)) be sure to read its documentation. See also [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html), [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) -to be used as `ps $$`, [pstree(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html), [top(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

See also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You might try `cat /proc/$$/limits` or `/bin/cat /proc/self/limits` in your terminal before running your program there. Perhaps `/bin/cat /proc/version` could be needed to understand more.

Your Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) can also be configured to avoid `core` dumps. Ask for details on [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) and read more about [SE Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). Some Linux kernels accept `gzcat /proc/config.gz` as root, but other don't, to query their configuration. You could need root access with [sudo(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) or [su(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html). See [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

On Linux, you might be interested by Ian Taylor [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) are using it.

My suggestion is to improve the source code of your application to use [syslog(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) to log all the program arguments. If you compile your application with some recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (in 2023), you could pass both `-O2` optimization and `-g` debugging flags to compiler and perhaps even use Ian Lance Taylor [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). If using the [git](https://git-scm.com/) version control system you can embed version ids in the executable (like [RefPerSys](https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys/) is doing).

Comment: With a previous employer, some of my colleagues ran "pstack" in order to see the stack trace of a core dump. Maybe this might also contain the executable's name?

Comment: We have a mechanism in place where we get the stack trace but unfortunately it is not available because of the error which is mention
`ss: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), too many program header sections (6841)`

Comment: `file` fails miserably for me: my executable is launched with a shell wrapper, with a very long command line. `file` fails to print the meaningful part of it. More answers are welcome.

Comment: Your shell wrapper should be improved to log (using [logger(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html)....) the full command line. Or your executable source code should store it in some file (perhaps under `/tmp/`)

Comment: Actually some (conventional) file under `/var/tmp/` should be a better place and it survives reboot. Alternatively use [syslog(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) in your source code.

Comment: A possibility might be some segmentation violation or (less likely) some hardware failure. Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)